# Apache gives Access denied on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, apache, macos-catalina

I have Apache webserver (the one supplied by Apple) running on my Macbook and it ran flawlessly, until I upgraded to Catalina 10.15.
I used the same httpd.conf, but now it is displaying

You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

I thought is was folder access by Catalina, but I don't know how to let Apache access the web root folder (which is inside my /Users/me/Documents folder)as Apache is not a normal /Application.

Port 80 is open when I check with lsof -nP -i4TCP:80 | grep LISTEN op nmap, so Apache does start.

I set a simple index.html in the root folder, but the problem persists.
And when I remove the .htaccess from the Apache root folder I get:

You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What can be the problem here ?

Answer (score 35):

I have found the solution, myself.

It is a `Catalina` issue:

1. Go to `System Preferences` => `Security & Privacy` => `Full Disk Access`
2. Click on the "+" button to add an app and go to the root folder of the disk and press
   Cmd + Shift + .(dot)
3. Go to /usr/sbin/ and select `httpd`.

That worked for me.

Comment: Full Disk Access?

Comment: This didn't fix it for me but I have the server app installed which is an added complication. The user dir config seems correct, when it's removed the url is not found vs forbidden.

Comment: This worked for me! Note that in step 2 one needs to click the lock at lower left corner to allow making changes. If no apps are listed, click the + to open the file selection panel.

Comment: I don't understand your step 2. what do you mean by go to the root folder of the disk? What folder do you referred to as root folder pls?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. I was trying to sort out this issues since last 2 days. I tried almost every solutions found on internet but no one worked for me.

Comment: Same problem for me in Big Sur and this resolved the issue.

Comment: It is odd that I am restarting /usr/sbin/apachectl but need to grant full access to /usr/sbin/httpd. Anyway, this solution works.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same error, the problem in my case was that macOS Catalina comes with the php module disable by default, in the error log apear as:

**tail /private/var/log/apache2/error_log**

> [Wed Feb 26 18:10:57.123036 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 3145] [client
>   127.0.0.1:53734] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/subdir/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by
>   Options directive

the apache server was loking for index.html instead of index.php so it was blocking the list directory, I uncommented the line **#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so** in **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf** and restart the apache server

> sudo apachectl restart

and it just work. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer save my life!

I tried all the different Apache configs possible, nothing worked.

Just a small correction for step 2 - click on the "+" sign to add an app, navigate to the root folder then press Cmd + Shift + .(dot) which will show all hidden folders and allow you to see the folder in step 3 (/usr/sbin/)

I wish Apple would have at least shown some error in such a case...

Comment: Damn Apple. Every time they release a new OS they break everyone's setup!

Answer (score -1):

Mac catalina apache forbidden issue

Step 1: sudo code /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Step 2:search for line #LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
and uncomment no need to delete it.

Step 3: sudo apachectl restart

Step 4: open Web browsers type localhost

Step5: Done

Comment: This worked for me. I had to uncomment php7_module and mod_rewrite