# 403 Forbidden Error on Mac OS Catalina (10.15.6) X Localhost

Tags: macos, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost

When i start my apache and type localhost on my browser, it shows me "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource." Last week, i was trying to use phpmyadmin and the first time i start the apachectl and type localhost, it was "it works!". But after i do some set up for my system file, i got Forbidden from the local host. My apachectl configtest is "Syntax OK".  I searched a lot and tried a lot, still can not solve this problem. Could anyone help me out with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuh6Z.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that the changes in the System file also changed the permission of the folders or files on your Apache directory. Try checking the file permission of your main page first (possibly index.php) or the main directory of your Apache service.

Comment: Could you teach me specifically? I am not sure how to check it or change it. Just treat me like a fool computer user.

Comment: Still no answer for this? I knew I shouldn't have updated to Catalina!

Comment: Try this solution I found on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455332/apache-gives-access-denied-on-macos-catalina). And you might also be correct that its a Catalina version related issue?